# SVG Image Logo Not Displaying In Firefox

Tags: html, css

My logo.svg file won't display in Firefox, but displays in all other browsers.

I have tried adding an img viewport, clearing the cache and updating Firefox, setting an explicit width in my html/css and nothing is working. Update- it is also worth noting that the same SVG file is used in the footer, and that picture is visible in Firefox, but where it should appear for the main logo it does not.

```
<style>
@media only screen and (min-width:450px) {
  logo.svg {
    width: 60%;
  }
}
</style>
<div class="container"><a href="#header" class="navbar-brand text-success"><img src="assets/img/logo.svg/"></a><button class="navbar-toggler collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#navcol-1"><span></span><span></span><span></span></button>
```

I've read that Firefox has image blocking functions and also doesn't always allow svgs. Does anyone know any workarounds?

Comment: What do you expect to match with the `logo.svg` selector? I don’t see a `<logo class="svg">` in your code.

Comment: it is within an image tag, which might be part of my problem. The css just sets the width of it, but it still doesn't explain why it is viewable in other browsers and not safari :(

Comment: I'm using SVGs a lot, firefox is my default browser, and what I've encountered mostly is changing the `font` will make SVGs disappear. Also, from what I know, SVGs need to be initialise outside. the best example is the `FontAwesome`

Comment: @EmmaChisholm _“It is within an image tag”_ — no, I’m referring to the selector in your CSS. _“The CSS just sets the width of it”_ — no, it doesn’t; the selector doesn’t match anything.

Comment: it's the file name?

Comment: `assets/img/logo.svg/` should be `assets/img/logo.svg` for starters, because `logo.svg` isn't a directory, its a file

Comment: Does this help?? https://stackoverflow.com/a/57367896/11700321

Comment: changing to assets/img/logo.svg gives me errors in css. I also tried giving the image a class name, calling the class name in css, and that didn't work either

Comment: Update- it is also worth noting that the same SVG file is used in the footer, and that picture is visible in Firefox, but where it should appear for the main logo it does not.

Comment: _"Firefox has image blocking functions and also doesn't always allow svgs"_ This is news to me.

Comment: Hey all, I was able to get it to work in Firefox by adding a width function to my image and cleaning up my code. Thank you all for the help.

Answer (score 0):

Should be `<img src="assets/img/logo.svg" />` instead of `<img src="assets/img/logo.svg/">` (slash *after*  the closing quote)